# need to get a page heading

Tags: c#, asp.net

This code when displays, it has the page heading of the main form, How can I get a page heading for this page?

```
<asp:Content ID="Content1" ContentPlaceHolderID="MainContent" Runat="Server">

    <table cellpadding="5" cellspacing="5" border="0">
        <tr>
            <td colspan="2" style="width:100px;">
                <dx:ASPxLabel ID="ASPxLabel1" runat="server" Text="Facility Name:"></dx:ASPxLabel>
                </td>
            <td colspan="9">
                <dx:ASPxTextBox ID="tbFacility" runat="server" Width="800px"></dx:ASPxTextBox>
                </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td colspan="2">
                <dx:ASPxLabel ID="ASPxLabel3" runat="server" Text="Resident Name:"></dx:ASPxLabel>
                </td>
            <td colspan="3">
                <dx:ASPxTextBox ID="tbResidentName" runat="server" Width="200px"></dx:ASPxTextBox>
                </td>
            <td >
                 <dx:ASPxLabel ID="ASPxLabel2" runat="server" Text="Physician Name:"></dx:ASPxLabel>
                </td>
            <td colspan="5">
                <dx:ASPxTextBox ID="tbPhysicianName" runat="server" Width="200px"></dx:ASPxTextBox>
                </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td colspan="2">
        <dx:ASPxLabel ID="ASPxLabel4" runat="server" Text="Allergies:"></dx:ASPxLabel>
            </td>
            <td colspan="9">
        <dx:ASPxTextBox ID="tbAllergies" runat="server" Width="200px"></dx:ASPxTextBox>
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td colspan="2">
        <dx:ASPxLabel ID="ASPxLabel5" runat="server" Text="Diagnosis:"></dx:ASPxLabel>
            </td>
            <td colspan="9">
        <dx:ASPxTextBox ID="tbDiagnosis" runat="server" Width="200px"></dx:ASPxTextBox>
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>
                    <dx:ASPxLabel ID="ASPxLabel8" runat="server" Text="DOB:" Width="50px"></dx:ASPxLabel>
                </td>
            <td align="left">
                    &nbsp;</td>
            <td>
                    <dx:ASPxTextBox ID="tbDOB" runat="server" Width="100px"></dx:ASPxTextBox>
                </td>
            <td align="right">
                    <dx:ASPxLabel ID="ASPxLabel9" runat="server" Text="Weight:" Width="50px"></dx:ASPxLabel>
                </td>
            <td align="left">
                    <dx:ASPxTextBox ID="tbWeight" runat="server" Width="100px"></dx:ASPxTextBox>
                </td>
            <td align="right">
                    <dx:ASPxLabel ID="ASPxLabel10" runat="server" Text="Height:" Width="50px"></dx:ASPxLabel>
                </td>
            <td align="left">
                    <dx:ASPxTextBox ID="tbHeight" runat="server" Width="100px"></dx:ASPxTextBox>
                </td>
            <td align="right">
                    <dx:ASPxLabel ID="ASPxLabel11" runat="server" Text="BP:" Width="50px"></dx:ASPxLabel>
                </td>
            <td align="left">
                     <dx:ASPxTextBox ID="tbBP" runat="server" Width="100px"></dx:ASPxTextBox>
                </td>
            <td align="right">
                    <dx:ASPxLabel ID="ASPxLabel12" runat="server" Text="Pulse:" Width="50px"></dx:ASPxLabel>
                </td>
            <td align="left">
                     <dx:ASPxTextBox ID="tbPulse" runat="server" Width="100px" ></dx:ASPxTextBox>
                </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td colspan="11" style="height: 180px">
                <dx:ASPxRoundPanel ID="ASPxRoundPanel1" runat="server" BackColor="#FFFFCC" 
                    HeaderText="REASON FOR REQUEST" Width="100%">
                    <HeaderStyle Font-Bold="True" />
                    <PanelCollection>
<dx:PanelContent ID="PanelContent1" runat="server" SupportsDisabledAttribute="True">
    <table cellpadding="2" style="width: 100%">
        <tr>
            <td width="200">
                <dx:ASPxCheckBox ID="ASPxCheckBox1" runat="server" CheckState="Unchecked" 
                    Text="Short term stay">
                </dx:ASPxCheckBox>
            </td>
            <td>
                <dx:ASPxTextBox ID="ASPxTextBox1" runat="server" Width="650px">
                </dx:ASPxTextBox>
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>
                <dx:ASPxCheckBox ID="ASPxCheckBox2" runat="server" CheckState="Unchecked" 
                    Text="Anticipated discharge date">
                </dx:ASPxCheckBox>
            </td>
            <td>
                <dx:ASPxTextBox ID="ASPxTextBox2" runat="server" Width="650px">
                </dx:ASPxTextBox>
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>
                <dx:ASPxCheckBox ID="ASPxCheckBox3" runat="server" CheckState="Unchecked" 
                    Text="Significant chagne in condition">
                </dx:ASPxCheckBox>
            </td>
            <td>
                <dx:ASPxTextBox ID="ASPxTextBox3" runat="server" Width="650px">
                </dx:ASPxTextBox>
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>
                <dx:ASPxCheckBox ID="ASPxCheckBox4" runat="server" CheckState="Unchecked" 
                    Text="Other">
                </dx:ASPxCheckBox>
            </td>
            <td>
                <dx:ASPxTextBox ID="ASPxTextBox4" runat="server" Width="650px">
                </dx:ASPxTextBox>
            </td>
        </tr>
    </table>
    <br />
                        </dx:PanelContent>
</PanelCollection>
                </dx:ASPxRoundPanel>
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td colspan="11">

                <dx:ASPxRoundPanel ID="ASPxRoundPanel2" runat="server" BackColor="#FFFFCC" 
                    HeaderText="CLINICAL DESCRIPTION OF NEED FOR REVIEW (please check all that apply and explain)" 
                    Width="100%" Height="416px">
                    <HeaderStyle Font-Bold="True" />
                    <PanelCollection>
<dx:PanelContent ID="PanelContent2" runat="server" SupportsDisabledAttribute="True">
    <table cellpadding="2" style="width: 100%">
        <tr>
            <td style="width:200px;">
                <dx:ASPxCheckBox ID="ASPxCheckBox5" runat="server" CheckState="Unchecked" 
                    Text="Anorexia and/or unplanned weight loss or gain">
                </dx:ASPxCheckBox>
            </td>
            <td>
                <dx:ASPxTextBox ID="ASPxTextBox5" runat="server" Width="650px">
                </dx:ASPxTextBox>
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>
                <dx:ASPxCheckBox ID="ASPxCheckBox6" runat="server" CheckState="Unchecked" 
                    Text="Behavioral changes, unusual behavioe patterns (incl. increased distressed behavior)">
                </dx:ASPxCheckBox>
            </td>
            <td>
                <dx:ASPxTextBox ID="ASPxTextBox6" runat="server" Width="650px">
                </dx:ASPxTextBox>
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>
                <dx:ASPxCheckBox ID="ASPxCheckBox7" runat="server" CheckState="Unchecked" 
                    Text="Bowel function changes incl. constipation; impaction">
                </dx:ASPxCheckBox>
            </td>
            <td>
                <dx:ASPxTextBox ID="ASPxTextBox7" runat="server" Width="650px">
                </dx:ASPxTextBox>
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td style="height: 27px">
                <dx:ASPxCheckBox ID="ASPxCheckBox8" runat="server" CheckState="Unchecked" 
                    Text="Confusion, Cognitive decline, worsening of dementia (incl. Delirium) of recent onset">
                </dx:ASPxCheckBox>
            </td>
            <td style="height: 27px">
                <dx:ASPxTextBox ID="ASPxTextBox8" runat="server" Width="650px">
                </dx:ASPxTextBox>
            </td>
        </tr>
         <tr>
            <td width="200">
                <dx:ASPxCheckBox ID="ASPxCheckBox9" runat="server" CheckState="Unchecked" 
                    Text="Dehydration, fluid/electrolyte imbalance">
                </dx:ASPxCheckBox>
            </td>
            <td>
                <dx:ASPxTextBox ID="ASPxTextBox9" runat="server" Width="650px" Text="   ">
                </dx:ASPxTextBox>
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>
                <dx:ASPxCheckBox ID="ASPxCheckBox10" runat="server" CheckState="Unchecked" 
                    Text="Depression; Mood disturbance">
                </dx:ASPxCheckBox>
            </td>
            <td>
                <dx:ASPxTextBox ID="ASPxTextBox10" runat="server" Width="650px">
                </dx:ASPxTextBox>
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>
                <dx:ASPxCheckBox ID="ASPxCheckBox11" runat="server" CheckState="Unchecked" 
                    Text="Dyshangia, swallowing difficulty">
                </dx:ASPxCheckBox>
            </td>
            <td>
                <dx:ASPxTextBox ID="ASPxTextBox11" runat="server" Width="650px">
                </dx:ASPxTextBox>
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>
                <dx:ASPxCheckBox ID="ASPxCheckBox12" runat="server" CheckState="Unchecked" 
                    Text="Excessive sedation, insomnia, or sleep disturbance">
                </dx:ASPxCheckBox>
            </td>
            <td>
                <dx:ASPxTextBox ID="ASPxTextBox12" runat="server" Width="650px">
                </dx:ASPxTextBox>
            </td>
        </tr>
         <tr>
            <td width="200">
                <dx:ASPxCheckBox ID="ASPxCheckBox13" runat="server" CheckState="Unchecked" 
                    Text="Falls, dizziness, or evidence of impaited condition">
                </dx:ASPxCheckBox>
            </td>
            <td>
                <dx:ASPxTextBox ID="ASPxTextBox13" runat="server" Width="650px">
                </dx:ASPxTextBox>
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>
                <dx:ASPxCheckBox ID="ASPxCheckBox14" runat="server" CheckState="Unchecked" 
                    Text="Gastrointestinal bleeding">
                </dx:ASPxCheckBox>
            </td>
            <td>
                <dx:ASPxTextBox ID="ASPxTextBox14" runat="server" Width="650px">
                </dx:ASPxTextBox>
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>
                <dx:ASPxCheckBox ID="ASPxCheckBox15" runat="server" CheckState="Unchecked" 
                    Text="Headaches, muscle pain, generalized aching or pain">
                </dx:ASPxCheckBox>
            </td>
            <td>
                <dx:ASPxTextBox ID="ASPxTextBox15" runat="server" Width="650px">
                </dx:ASPxTextBox>
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>
                <dx:ASPxCheckBox ID="ASPxCheckBox16" runat="server" CheckState="Unchecked" 
                    Text="rash; prutus">
                </dx:ASPxCheckBox>
            </td>
            <td>
                <dx:ASPxTextBox ID="ASPxTextBox16" runat="server" Width="650px">
                </dx:ASPxTextBox>
            </td>
        </tr>
         <tr>
            <td width="200">
                <dx:ASPxCheckBox ID="ASPxCheckBox17" runat="server" CheckState="Unchecked" 
                    Text="Seizure activity">
                </dx:ASPxCheckBox>
            </td>
            <td>
                <dx:ASPxTextBox ID="ASPxTextBox17" runat="server" Width="650px">
                </dx:ASPxTextBox>
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>
                <dx:ASPxCheckBox ID="ASPxCheckBox18" runat="server" CheckState="Unchecked" 
                    Text="Spontaneousor unexplained bleeding/bruising">
                </dx:ASPxCheckBox>
            </td>
            <td>
                <dx:ASPxTextBox ID="ASPxTextBox18" runat="server" Width="650px">
                </dx:ASPxTextBox>
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>
                <dx:ASPxCheckBox ID="ASPxCheckBox19" runat="server" CheckState="Unchecked" 
                    Text="Unexplained decline in functional status (e.g. ADL's, vision)">
                </dx:ASPxCheckBox>
            </td>
            <td>
                <dx:ASPxTextBox ID="ASPxTextBox19" runat="server" Width="650px">
                </dx:ASPxTextBox>
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>
                <dx:ASPxCheckBox ID="ASPxCheckBox20" runat="server" CheckState="Unchecked" 
                    Text="Urinary retention or incontinence">
                </dx:ASPxCheckBox>
            </td>
            <td>
                <dx:ASPxTextBox ID="ASPxTextBox20" runat="server" Width="650px">
                </dx:ASPxTextBox>
            </td>
        </tr>
    </table>
                        </dx:PanelContent>
</PanelCollection>
                </dx:ASPxRoundPanel>

            </td>
        </tr>

    </table>

<br />


</asp:Content>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like you're using a Master Page.

If you want a specific heading for each page (I am assuming you mean the title? i.e. what the browser has as the window title) then you need to specify a value in the `<title>` tag.

If you don't already have a placeholder for the `<head>` content, make one, and use the title from there.

i.e.

in your page:

```
<asp:Content ID="headContent" ContentPlaceHolderID="headContentPlaceholder" Runat="Server">
    <title><asp:Label> .... </asp:Label></title>
</asp:Content>
```

in your master:

```
<head>
    <asp:ContentPlaceholder ID="headContentPlaceholder" Runat="Server"></asp:Content>
</head>
```